# Android : Enter a new row to db

Tags: android

I'm having some weird problem while I'am making the checkbook application.

The problem is when I reset the cash value by making another row in CashBalancTable(TABLE_CB)

Even though the record was made successfully, the CashSetting activity become dead.(make an error

message and go back to previous activity). "Unfortunately, money has stopped" ==> error popup window

Because of that, I can't activate the startActivity line in the last of CashSetting. Could you tell

me what is the problem? Thanks.

CashBalanceTable class is just for moving the data.

```
**//CashBalanceTable class**
public class CashBalanceTable {

    private int id;
    private int cash;

    public CashBalanceTable() {}
    public CashBalanceTable(int id, int cash)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.cash = cash;
    }
    public CashBalanceTable(int cash)
    {
        this.cash = cash;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setCash(int cash)
    {
        this.cash = cash;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public int getCash()
    {
        return cash;
    }
}


**//CashSetting.java**

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CashSetting extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button  enterButton;
    EditText editText1;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    TextView textView3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cash_setting);

        enterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enterButton);
        editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);     
        textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    }

    public void initializingCash(View view)
    {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);        
        if(editText1.getText().toString() == null)
            return;

        int cash = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());    

        CashBalanceTable cb = new CashBalanceTable(cash);
        long id = dbHelper.insertCash(cb);

        if(id == -1)
        {
            Message.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
        }
        else
        {
            Message.message(this, id + " row created");
        }

        editText1.setText(null);
        textView3.setText("Your cash balance set to " + cash + " won");

        startActivity(new Intent(CashSetting.this, SettingActivity.class));
    }
}








**//This is insertCash method in DatabaseHelper class**
public long insertCash(CashBalanceTable cb) //done
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CASH, cb.getCash());

    //insert a row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_CB, null, values);    
    return id;
}
```

**Just for you reference, below is logcat**

```
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): Process: com.example.money, PID: 2069
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): ... 11 more
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): at com.example.money.CashSetting.initializingCash(CashSetting.java:53)
11-15 11:01:05.641: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): ... 14 more
11-15 11:01:12.993: W/EGL_genymotion(2097): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 11:22:56.137: W/EGL_genymotion(2097): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 11:22:57.605: W/EGL_genymotion(2097): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 11:23:48.437: W/EGL_genymotion(2097): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 11:23:48.721: W/EGL_genymotion(2097): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 11:24:04.189: D/dalvikvm(2097): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 158K, 6% free 3702K/3916K, paused 8ms, total 14ms
11-15 11:24:04.325: W/EGL_genymotion(2097): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 11:24:06.821: W/EGL_genymotion(2097): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 11:24:09.073: W/EGL_genymotion(2097): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 11:24:12.073: D/AndroidRuntime(2097): Shutting down VM
11-15 11:24:12.073: W/dalvikvm(2097): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d6cb20)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): Process: com.example.money, PID: 2097
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): ... 11 more
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): at com.example.money.CashSetting.initializingCash(CashSetting.java:53)
11-15 11:24:12.077: E/AndroidRuntime(2097): ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems related at

```
public void initializingCash(View view)
```

The logCat says that you are trying to call this method in an OnClick method (somewhere in your code)

i think the problem starts when you try to use CashSettings.this in the startActivity, the reference could be NULL because you are inside the OnClick method (NullPointerException at line 53 of CashSettings activity)

Try to set a CashSettings variable in onCreate, add this

```
CashSettings csActivity;
```

under those lines

```
Button  enterButton;
EditText editText1;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
TextView textView3;
```

then in onCreate add this line

```
csActivity = this;
```

then launch the intent with this

```
startActivity(new Intent(csActivity, SettingActivity.class));
```

And let us know if something changed :)